Why does Google Search Console show higher impressions than the search volume for a keyword
In Google Search Console, I’ve noticed that certain keywords are generating a much higher number of impressions than their reported search volumes, according to keyword research tools. For example, a keyword with a search volume of 5,000 may show 8,000+ impressions in Search Console.
I am trying to understand why this discrepancy occurs and what factors might contribute to impressions exceeding the standard search volume. From what I understand:
Multiple Appearances: A single query might result in multiple impressions if my page appears in different positions across multiple pages of results.
Related Queries: Search Console might be counting impressions from related, long-tail, or semantically similar keywords, not just exact matches.
Personalised and Localised Results: Google’s personalisation and localisation of search results might lead to more impressions in certain regions or personalised settings.
Could someone clarify if these are the primary reasons, or are there other factors I should consider? Also, any tips on how to interpret or use these impressions effectively for SEO strategy would be appreciated!
